# Let $f : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ $f(x) = \sqrt {x}$. Prove $f$ is continuous at $x = 4$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x) = \sqrt {x}$. Prove that $f$ is continuous at $x = 4$.

Comment: so, hmmm where are you stucked?

Comment: Yes, please include some idea of what you tried or what your thoughts are.  This site isn't for just solving your homework.

Comment: Note that $a-b = {a^2-b^2 \over a+b}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $(x_n)\subseteq\ [0,\infty)$ be a sequence converging to $4$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Then $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}\ \text{such that}\ \forall n>N,|x_n-4|<2\epsilon$. Let $n>N$. Then $|x_n-4|=|\sqrt{x_n}-2||\sqrt{x_n}+2|<2\epsilon$. Therefore $|\sqrt{x_n}-2|<\frac{2\epsilon}{|\sqrt{x_n}+2|}\leq\ \frac{2\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$. Therefore $(f(x_n))$ converges to $2=f(4)$. Hence $f$ is continuous at $4$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon >0$

$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{4}|=|\sqrt{x}-2|=|\frac{(\sqrt{x}-2)(\sqrt{x}+2)}{\sqrt{x}+2}|=\frac{|x-4|}{\sqrt{x}+2} \leqslant \frac{|x-4|}{2}$ because $\sqrt{x}+2 \geqslant 2$

Take $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and you are done.